# Woocommerce 3.1 Add product image to order confirmation email not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using the following code in my theme functions.php to **add product images in order email**. But the image is not showing in the email. Did I miss anything? I'm using **WooCommerce 3.1**

```
function sww_add_images_woocommerce_emails( $output, $order ) {

    // set a flag so we don't recursively call this filter
    static $run = 0;

    // if we've already run this filter, bail out
    if ( $run ) {
        return $output;
    }

    $args = array(
        'show_sku'      => false,
        'show_image'    => true,
        'image_size'    => array( 100, 100 ),
    );

    // increment our flag so we don't run again
    $run++;

    // if first run, give WooComm our updated table
    return $order->email_order_items_table( $args );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_table', 'sww_add_images_woocommerce_emails', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Downvote for this question?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code in functions.php inside your theme folder.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'iconic_email_order_items_args', 10, 1 );

function iconic_email_order_items_args( $args ) {

    $args['show_image'] = true;

    return $args;

}
```

Comment: This will display images in a tiny thumbnail format, you can specify the image size using the following code `$args['image_size'] = array( 100, 100 );`